unknown command "attestation" for "gh"
I was trying to upgrade all Homebrew packages with
brew upgrade

and encountered the following error:
unknown command "attestation" for "gh"


I hadn't updated or upgraded Homebrew in a while. I updated Homebrew first using
brew update

and then tried to upgrade all packages. It appears brew is using gh attestation now, but the version of gh I had installed did not have this subcommand.
To fix this, I manually upgraded gh first, and then upgraded all packages:
brew upgrade gh
brew upgrade


Thanks! This worked for me. I'm surprised that running brew upgrade alone didn't fix the issue. Seems upgrading gh should be higher in the default priority.
